# How to stop Microsoft Skype For Business for starting after reboot

Tags: macos, skype

How do I stop Microsoft Skype For Business from automatically starting every time I rebook macOS?

Comment: Why did you re-post your own question and accept the same solution?

Comment: Sorry I forgot I posted the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the Login Items?

`System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items`

[image]

To remove an item, choose it and hit the <kbd>-</kbd>-button at the bottom. Just checking or unchecking the *hide* radio button won't disable the login item!

Comment: Thank you. I did 'uncheck' this option but it seems it only works if you completely remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in the Skype settings, you can always keep apps from automatically starting in System Preferences:

Apple menu -> System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items.

Simply find Skype in the list and press the [-] button on the bottom.